# MySql workbench не загружается

Tags: mysql

> > Problem signature:
> >       Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH

Application Name: MySQLWorkbench.exe

Application Version:  6.3.7.0

Application Timestamp:    5758217b

Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll

Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17514

Fault Module Timestamp:   4ce7c78c

Exception Code:   e0434352

Exception Offset: 000000000000a49d

OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

Locale ID:    1033

Additional Information 1: 2413
  Additional Information 2: 2413de213f38e5efe700010a55469627
  Additional Information 3: 57bb
  Additional Information 4: 57bb597d10cfc54126c0a7d525027b8d

- Не понимаю в чём проблема.. Установка `vcredist_x64` `vcredist_x86`не помогает!

Comment: Если не сложно сообщите версию операционной системы?

Comment: Переустановил операционку и все решилось)